# Find selected NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I have a scroll view with text views.  How do I find which text view is currently selected?

The delegate methods in NSTextDelegate only see to work once you start editing not when it's first selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NSTextView needs to be the first responder to be selected. You could override

```
-(void)becomeFirstResponder;
```

throw a notification with an id, to find out which NSTextView was selected.

Comment: Thanks!  I really like that approach.